# How to invalid cache when using ListGrid and Datasource

Tags: datasource, smartgwt, listgrid

As per what I found reading other sites :

SmartGWT uses data caching to optimize client-server connections and reduce network traffic. In your example, let's say you have the following in your database:

**one word**

**two words**

**one sentence**

When you type word, the fetch returns:

**one word**

**two words**

These values are cached in your client.

When you add one to word, because this is a more restraining search criteria, no need to server fetch, only client filter and the result is:

**one word**

Is there a way of avoiding this and make the search always against the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can user the following properties of **DataSource** to turn caching OFF.

```
dataSource.setCacheAllData(false);
dataSource.setAutoCacheAllData(false);
```

If you want to turn the caching On, pass "true" to both function calls.

Answer (score 0):

manually calling invalidateCache() on listgrid component should run the fetch method with actual criteria